# Regex to retrieve everything between '|Description=' and '|Category'

Tags: php, regex

Given the following text:

```
|Description=This is the start of the ...

... <strong>description</strong> of a product that can span over multiple lines
|Category=Product
```

How can I retrieve the text between *|Description=* and *|Category=Product*?

In the above example, the return string should only contain:

```
This is the start of the ...

... <strong>description</strong> of a product that can span over multiple lines
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this pattern

```
(?<=\|Description=)(.*)(?=\|Category)
```

Run it with `dot all` and `multiline` flags.

Comment: Thanks, this is working. Out of interest, why would preg_match('/(?<=\|Description=)(.*)(?=\|Category)/sm', $text, $matches)) return an array with two duplicate return strings?

Comment: @MichaelP: I am sorry, I have no idea why that might be :(

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern `\|Description=(.*?)\|Category=`